# What is the best practice for storing passwords for your rails application?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, security, smtp, passwords

What is the best way to store username/passwords for fields like the ones below (user_name, password) for all environment config files

```
  config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
    address:              'smtp.gmail.com',
    port:                 587,
    domain:               'gmail.com',
    user_name:            ENV["GMAIL_USERNAME"],
    password:             ENV["GMAIL_PASSWORD"],
    authentication:       :plain,
    enable_starttls_auto: true
  }
```

or in database.yml (username, password)

```
default: &default
  adapter: postgresql
  host: 127.0.0.1
  username: postgres
  password: postgres
  encoding: unicode
  # For details on connection pooling, see Rails configuration guide
  # https://guides.rubyonrails.org/configuring.html#database-pooling
  pool: <%= ENV.fetch("RAILS_MAX_THREADS") { 5 } %>
```

What is the best practice to put in those fields? and assuming it isn't plaintext, where/how are they best stored?

Comment: For me works using env. variables, but clearly must be better ways to do this. Maybe [the answers for this question](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/168993/226411) could give you some ideas about some more powerful options.

Comment: Rails has this built in with rails credentials